# Lambda Expressions and Strings

Tags: python, lambda

I am just learning about lambda expressions, and I am wondering how I could use it to count the number of vowels in a string. For example,
I am using the following:

```
result = lambda i, y: i + 1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU"
print(result(0,s)
```

However, I recieve a syntax error. 
Also, just to clarify my understanding, a lambda expression returns the expression following the colon. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Silvio for your help! Populating a list like you suggested gave me an answer that wasn't quite as clear as I wanted as it returned

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

While a generator returned

```
<generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000028884166C00>
```

In the end, I used sum on the generator to get

```
result = lambda i, y: sum(i + 1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU")
print(result(0, s))
```

Which gave me the answer of 5.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the parse that's ambiguous. Consider

```
result = lambda i, y: (i + 1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU")
```

Of course, now it will return a generator object, which won't print as nicely. If you want a list, you might try

```
result = lambda i, y: [i + 1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU"]
```

Comment: OP said they wanted to return a count of vowels not a list

Answer (score 1):

To me this is an improper use of `lambda` to begin with, as `lambda`'s are supposed to be function definitions with no name or more or less a throw away function. Also the reason you got a Syntax Error is your generator expression is incorrect, use `sum` for something like this.

```
result = lambda y: sum(1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU")
```

You can even use map for this:

```
result = lambda y: sum(map(y.count, "aeoiuAEIOU"))
```

But this could be done more legibly and imo more correctly with an actual function definition and you can include more statements

```
#more appropriately named count_vowels vs result and s vs y
def count_vowels(s):
    _s = s.lower()
    return sum(map(_s.count, 'aeiou')
```

You can also use `re` *(regex)* for this too:

```
import re

def count_vowels(s): return len(re.findall("[aeiou]", s, re.I))
```

The `re.I` ignores case so no need to worry about capsvs uncaps

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use one parameter in `lambda`:

```
result = lambda y: sum(x in "aeoiuAEIOU" for x in y)
```

and the syntax error is not special with `lambda`:

```
In [10]: def bar(i, y):
    ...:     return i + 1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU"
  File "<ipython-input-10-96fcd0959145>", line 2
    return i + 1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the real issue is that `i + 1 for x in y if x in "aeoiuAEIOU"` is an invalid expression in Python.

Comment: Is the reason that you can use the expression `x in ...` because non-empty strings are truthy and True == 1, and thus it would sum 1 every time there is a value?

Comment: @Trebond In Python, `isinstance(True, int)` is True and `issubclass(bool, int)` is True. So True is 1 and False is 0, so you just sum them together.